# Реализация выборки столбца матрицы в C++Builder

Tags: алгоритм, c++

Раньше моделировал в Mathcad, теперь появилась необходимость изучить C++ Builder.

В Mathcad есть операция `<>`, которая выделяет определенный столбец матрицы. Подскажите, как ее реализовать? В частности так, чтобы использовать в выражении.

[image]

У меня получился следующий код:

```
int **Array;
int n = 5;
Array = new int*[n];
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
  Array[i] = new int[n];
}
fstream stream(".\\12.txt");
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
  {
    stream >> Array[i][j];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j = n; j++)
      {
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Это достаточно правильная реализация, или её можно улучшить?

Comment: Извиняюсь, что не поздоровался)
Здравствуйте)
Заранее спасибо за любую помощь!

Comment: в C++ простейшая матрица - это двумерный массив, элементом будет ``a[i,j]``, следовательно ваш столбец ``R<n>`` будет набор элементов(тоже массив, но одномерный) ``a[0..n-1][n]``

Comment: Код добавлен в вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Извините, а не подскажите, почему код при задании статистической матрицы выдает всякую ерунду:

   int array[3]={3,40,67};
   ofstream stream("ot.txt");
   stream<<array[3];

при выводе через `Stringgrid` то же самое, т.е.

> 10578756

Comment: индексация идёт с нуля, т.е. у вас
<pre>
int array[3]={3,40,67};
array[0] == 3;
array[1] == 40;
array[2] == 67;
array[3] == хз что.
</pre>
будьте добры, примите ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Примерно да, только у вас с циклами проблема - закройте первые 2 цикла перед 2-мя последними.

А поледний цикл

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
{ 
    Array[i][N];//этот массив и будет вашим R<n>
}
```

в котором **N** - номер необходимого столбца.

Comment: Спасибо!затупил, исправил, ко все равно не то...
выдает фигню

Comment: Что именно выдает? Как исправили?

Comment: Вообще задача заключается в действиях над матрицами, но уже на стадии их задания получается ошибка.Попробовал задать одномерный массив тоже ошибка
int array3[2];
array3[0]=2;
array3[1]=9;
ofstream stream2("outtt.txt");
stream2<<array3[2];
в текстовый фал выводит одно число 3.

Comment: Все, разобрался-опять затупил), огромное всем спасибо за помошь!